# Display crystal report in a Modal popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I created a crystal report which works fine. I now want to display it in a bootstrap popup modal
but I always get an empty modal or it works fine with a gridview.
I would like to know how to fix this problem? thank you for helping me

Comment: Can you please share your relevant code so we can get a proper idea and try to give you the best solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thank you for your answers here is the code;

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ModalpopupTest.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <style type="text/css">
        .Modalbackground
        {
            background-color:black;
            filter: alpha(opacity=40);
            opacity:0.4;
        }
        .modalPopup{
            background-color:#ffffff;
            width:100%;
            border:3px solid #0DA9D0;
            height:75%;
        }
        .modalPopup .header{
            background-color:#2fbdf1;
            height:30px;
            color:white;
            line-height:30px;
            text-align:center;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        .modalPopup .footer{
            padding:3px;
        }
        .modalPopup .button{
            height:2px;
            color:white;
            line-height:23px;
            text-align:center;
            font-weight:bold;
            cursor:pointer;
            background-color:red;
            border:1px solid #5c5c5c;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
      <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOpen" OnClick="btnOpen_Click" Text="Show Popup" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CausesValidation="false" />
       <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdpImprimer" PopupControlID="pImprimer" TargetControlID="lblmdpIndex" CancelControlID="btnClose" PopupDragHandleControlID="headerdiv" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="Modalbackground"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="pImprimer" CssClass="table-responsive" runat="server">
            <div id="headerdiv" class="header"></div>
         
            <div class="mb-3" style="overflow:scroll;width:100%;height:75%">
   <div class="modal-body card-body bg-default-gradient modal-fullscreen">
       <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="cr" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footerdiv" class="footer">
                <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Fermer" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
          <asp:Label ID="lblmdpIndex" runat="server" Text="Label" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
    </form>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and c# code

```
 private void BingReport()
        {
            try
            {
                d.connecter();
                d.da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FORMAT([Dates],'dd-MM-yy') as [Dates],d.[Designation] as Agence,c.Designation as Depot,b.[Reference] as reference,b.Designation as Produit,e.Nom as Client,[Numpiece],[TRANSPORTEUR],[Chauffeur],[VEHICUL],[QUANTITE],[PU] from [dbo].[VenteClients] a inner join [dbo].[article] b on b.Idarticle=a.Idarticle inner join [dbo].[Depot] c on c.IdDepot=a.IdDepot inner join [dbo].[Agences] d on d.IdAgences=a.IdAgences inner join [dbo].[Clients] e on e.[IdClients]=a.IdClients where  [Numpiece]='80279' and c.Designation='SCDP DOUALA'", d.con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                d.da.Fill(ds, "Editbonlivraison");
                d.deconnecter();
                ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument(); // creating object of crystal report
                crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/EDITIONBONS.rpt")); // path of report 
                crystalReport.SetDataSource(ds); // binding datatable
                cr.ReportSource = crystalReport;
                mdpImprimer.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        protected void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BingReport();
        }
```